# Can we identify if 2 events $A$ and $B$ are independent (or dependent) without knowing $P(A \cap B)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

[image]

The above diagram certainly tells us that that the 2 events $A$ and $B$ are not mutually exclusive. But what do we know for sure about their independence. Can we tell anything about their independence without knowing the values for $P(A \cap B)$ .

Let $P(A) = 0.4$ and $P(B) = 0.8$

Comment: No, you can't.  Some people might try to draw the balls "to scale" as it were, but this picture clearly doesn't make that attempt.  Thus, we can't guess at the numerical value of $P(A\cap B)$ from the picture.

Comment: Is $$\Omega=A\cup B$$ ?

Comment: @Cretin2 No it isnt. $A ∪ B $ is a proper subset of $ Ω$

Comment: @lulu so we cannot say anything about independence correct ?

Comment: The picture really carries minimal information.  Sure, one can imagine that it tells us that $P(A\cap B)>0$ but we knew that already (it must be at least $.2$ in fact).  And it seems to tell us that $P(A\cap B)<.4$  which we did not know a priori, but that's it.

Comment: Think of it like the pictures one draws in elementary Geometry.  At best, they tell us the general relations between the various things under discussion but you shouldn't use the picture to decide if some angle "looks like" a right angle or if some triangle "appears to be" isosceles and so on.

Comment: We know that $$p(A\cup B)=1.2-p(A\cap B)\leq 1\Rightarrow p(A\cap B)\geq 0.2$$ ?

Comment: @lulu Understood. I have a really hard time imagining how 2 events that are not mutually exclusive can be independent. II intuitively think of them as depedent. The diagram tells us nothing about independence. But only tells about mutal exclusivity. What I want to know is whether the independence of 2 events $A$ and $B$ is solely dependent on how we define $A$ and $B$   or is it also the result of something else.

Comment: I think you are confused.  Events which are mutually exclusive *can not* be independent (excluding degenerate cases, wherein one or the other event has probability $0$).  Informally speaking, "independent" means knowing whether or not one event has occurred tells you nothing about whether or not the other occurred.  For mutually exclusive events, knowing that one occurred tells you that the other did not occur.

Comment: @lulu I've figured out mutually exclusive events.  I have trouble with events that are NOT mutually exclusive like the venn diagram shows. The rest of my confusion is like I mentioned above. Can you please clarify that for me

Comment: You said "I have a really hard time imagining how 2 events that are not mutually exclusive can be independent."  That statement is badly confused.  *Only* events which are not mutually exclusive can be independent.  As for the rest of what you wrote, I have literally no idea what you are asking.  Obviously, independence and such depend on the definitions of $A$ and $B$.  How could it be otherwise?

Comment: The usual examples of independent events are things like:  toss a fair penny and a fair dime.  Let $A$ be the event 'the penny comes up $H$.  Let $B$ be the event 'the dime comes up $H$.  Then $A,B$ are independent.  A more subtle example is:  toss a fair die.  Let $A$ be the event 'the toss is even' and let $B$ be the event 'the toss is $1$ or $2$'.  Then $A,B$ are indepednent.

Comment: @lulu Okay. So I am completely wrong about that then. But what truly confuses me is this https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/177878/336535  This answer convinced me that mutually not exclusive events can be dependent and thats also why I have a hard time imagining how they could be independent.

Comment: I think you should just write out a lot of examples.  It should be easy for you to produce examples of dependent events which are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130579/discussion-between-artaxerxes-and-lulu).

Comment: No need to chat.  Just think through examples.  Vary my example with dice, for instance.

Comment: Only events that are not mutually exclusive can be independent. But dependent events can be mutually exclusive or not mutually exclusive correct ? Thanks for clarifying. I think I will write down a lot of examples